# SecKeychainFindInternetPassword is not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, keychain

I have a problem with storing and reading from my keychain. First I tried to store use a char like this "account_name" in the Method SecKeychainFindInternetPassword for accountname and this runs. But now i would like to store a variable inside. But if i run this code the Programm cannot find the Keychain Item.
Please Help me.
(Sorry for my bad Englisch, i am a german student)

```
-(void)StorePasswordKeychain:(void*)password :(UInt32)passwordLength
{
char *userString;

userString = (char *)[_username UTF8String];
SecKeychainAddInternetPassword(
                               NULL,
                               StrLength("myserver.com"),
                               "myserver.com",
                               0,
                               NULL,
                               StrLength(userString),
                               userString,
                               0,
                               nil,
                               0,
                               kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS,
                               kSecAuthenticationTypeHTMLForm,
                               passwordLength,
                               password,
                               NULL
                               );
}

-(OSStatus)GetPasswordKeychain:(void *)passwordData :(UInt32 *)passwordLength
{
OSStatus status;
char *userString;

userString = (char *)[_username UTF8String];
status = SecKeychainFindInternetPassword(
                                NULL,
                                StrLength("myserver.com"),
                                "myserver.com",
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                StrLength(userString),
                                userString,
                                0,
                                nil,
                                0,
                                kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS,
                                kSecAuthenticationTypeHTMLForm,
                                passwordLength,
                                passwordData,
                                NULL
                                );
return status;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two suggestions.. don't pass null into itemRef (the last arg). Then you'll have a pointer to the keychain you wish to modify.

Also, you should really check the error code to see if your add function worked.

```
OSStatus result = SecKeychainAddInternetPassword(
                           NULL,
                           StrLength("myserver.com"),
                           "myserver.com",
                           0,
                           NULL,
                           StrLength(userString),
                           userString,
                           0,
                           nil,
                           0,
                           kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS,
                           kSecAuthenticationTypeHTMLForm,
                           passwordLength,
                           password,
                           NULL
                           );
if(result != noErr){
    NSLog(@"Error AddPassword result=:%d", result );
}
```

This is my sample program with the same code that you provided and it works fine.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    char *inputpassword = "topsecret";
    UInt32 inputpassLength = strlen(inputpassword);
    OSStatus status;
    NSString *_username = @"account_name";

    char *userString;

    userString = (char *)[_username UTF8String];
    status = SecKeychainAddInternetPassword(
                                   NULL,
                                   StrLength("myserver.com"),
                                   "myserver.com",
                                   0,
                                   NULL,
                                   StrLength(userString),
                                   userString,
                                   0,
                                   nil,
                                   0,
                                   kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS,
                                   kSecAuthenticationTypeHTMLForm,
                                   inputpassLength,
                                   inputpassword,
                                   NULL
                                   );


    NSLog(@"Adding Status:%d", status);



    UInt32 returnpasswordLength = 0;
    char *passwordData;

    status = SecKeychainFindInternetPassword(
                                             NULL,
                                             StrLength("myserver.com"),
                                             "myserver.com",
                                             0,
                                             NULL,
                                             StrLength(userString),
                                             userString,
                                             0,
                                             nil,
                                             0,
                                             kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS,
                                             kSecAuthenticationTypeHTMLForm,
                                             &returnpasswordLength,
                                             (void *)&passwordData,
                                             NULL
                                             );

    NSLog(@"Retrieving status:%d", status);

    NSLog(@"Password:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:passwordData
                                                   length:returnpasswordLength
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the answer. I have checked the error code and the Keychain Item exists. And if i use the Keychain Utility i can see the Item and i see that the password and everything is ok, but if i look at the error of the find method it says that the item does´t exist....

Comment: Are you adding and removing multiple keychain items? If not, keep the itemRef on the creation.

Comment: Hey. I am using the read method at the beginning of the program. If the item isn´t there i add it to the keychain, to use it at the next programm start. I have tried your code and i have the same Problem Code:-25300 ....

Comment: @Max difficult to say what's happening without seeing your entire app, maybe _username is being modified? The functions posted in the sample terminal app version are correct. Did you try copy/pasting the sample terminal app version I posted?

Comment: Hey, yes i tried it and sometimes it works. But in one of ten cases i have the same Problems. Same Problem with other Keychain or other mac.

Comment: @SnowMaxi I happen to have this problem right now, and , i somehow manage to figure out what is going wrong... i got 25300 too. then, i check every parameters and i find: the StrLength is to blame. this macro will give you unexpected result. you can use strlen. and you might get it work. also, you can find out by cmd+click the StrLength Macro:)